# Regular Expression Check for Capital Names in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, count

I have a database, which holds many first names, occurring like the following pattern:

The name can consist of many first names (like double, or triple names), separated by either a '-' or a ' '.
Each of the names consists of either lowercase or UPPERCASE letters or a capital first letter and the rest lowercase.

I would like to write a query to count all names which have either just UPPERCASE letters, or do not have a capital letter after a break of two words.

#### Sample *Table* and *Data*

```
CREATE TABLE names( name VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY(name) ); 
INSERT INTO names values('Veronika isabella'); 
INSERT INTO names values('Veronika Isabella'); 
INSERT INTO names values('Michael Karl Otto- Emil'); 
INSERT INTO names values('Michael karl-Otto-emil'); 
INSERT INTO names values('philipp'); 
INSERT INTO names values('Philipp');
```

Comment: if possible give sample table with data

Comment: "Veronika isabella" - `count++` 
"Veronika Isabella" - `count=count`
"Michael Karl Otto Emil" - `count=count`
"Michael karl-Otto-emil" - `count++`
"philipp" - `count++`
"Philipp" - `count=count`

Comment: I meant `create table`  _script_ of your _table_ and `insert into table` for test your case in my environment

Comment: Well, its just a one column table with different names..

`CREATE TABLE names(
   name VARCHAR,
   PRIMARY KEY(name)
);

INSERT INTO names values('Veronika isabella');
INSERT INTO names values('Veronika Isabella');
INSERT INTO names values('Michael Karl Otto- Emil');
INSERT INTO names values('Michael karl-Otto-emil');
INSERT INTO names values('philipp');
INSERT INTO names values('Philipp');`

Comment: It's fine if this is just a programming exersise but please don't do this in the real world. Not everyone has "First" and "Last", or "Given" and "Family" names. They're not always written in the same order. They aren't always capitalised. Doing this in a real world app will make Joe McDonald, Alan de Silva (`"de Silva" is the last name), Prince, Olga D'Amico, and many others very angry. Don't do it. Names are weird and don't follow easily encoded rules. See http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: These are just first names which follow this rules. It is required to displyaing this names and I'm not touching the last names.

Comment: Maybe as simple as `where name <> initcap(name)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Excellent idea. Might be just what the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) AS misfits
FROM   names
WHERE  name !~ '[[:lower:]]'   -- not a single lower case letter
OR     name ~ '\m[[:lower:]]'  -- lower case letter at beginning of a word
OR     name ~ '[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]'; -- lower case letter after upper case
```

[Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Or maybe [**`initcap()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) fits your requirements ([like a_horse commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459769/regular-expression-check-for-capital-names-in-postgresql/26466259?noredirect=1#comment41574691_26459769)).

```
SELECT count(*) AS misfits
FROM   names
WHERE  name <> initcap(name);
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12627/6)

Comment: this gets pretty close to my predicted count, but I think there are still names missing, where the first letter isn't capital. Are these also possible to find with this statement?

Comment: @MichaelWerner: Should be in the question then ... I added a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately initcap qualifies words as alphanumerical characters seperated by non-AN-chars.  My names contain all non-AN-chars but words are qualified as any set of characters, as they also contain titles like ",MSc" seperated by either '-' or ' '